# Rewrite rule with deleting a pattern or backward reference in the path with AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, rewrite, amazon-elb

Using AWS ELB, I want the folowing rewrite rule :

`https://example.com/dl/toto.jpg` should transform to `https://dl.example.com/toto.jpg`

I tried two ways to do this :

- matching path `/dl/*` and return a path deleting `/dl/` somethink like `#{path/dl//}`.
- use a backward reference to the match with `/dl/\(*\)` and replacing with path \1

2 method return invalid path message :(

Is it possible to do this with AWS ELB ? And if yes, how can I do that ?